# Change TextStyle Programmatically

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, styles

```
@Override
protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final Chat.MessagesViewHolder holder, final int position, @NonNull final MessagesHelper model) {
       holder.mDisplayText.setBackgroundColor(BackgoundColorSent);
}
```

I can do that for textColor and size but there is no method for `textStyle`. I'm using a `firebaseRecyclerAdapter` and wish to change the `style` of the item of recyclerView programmatically as the user pleases.

Comment: sse `TextView#setTextAppearance`

Comment: setTextAppearence() What should come inside bracket.. like i want only 3 styles bold italic and bolditalic @pskink

Comment: then why not using `textView.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);`

Comment: @MichelleKinsten try this.. `textView.setTextAppearance(getActivity(), R.style.fontForNotificationLandingPage);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `setTypeface` for applying styles to your text

```
textView.setTypeface(Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);
```

**Other Typefaces you can use are:**

1. Typeface.BOLD
2. Typeface.NORMAL
3. Typeface.SANS_SERIF
4. Typeface.MONOSPACE
5. Typeface.ITALIC

Answer (score 0):

It's better to change the texstyle with the command in the xml file "textStyle()"

You need to change it in your layout from your itemview.

I hope I could help you.

[image]

Comment: I want the user to select textStyle for all the items... how do i achieve that